# Limit SharePoint search on local site only

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint Online tenant with global search is on. I have a SharePoint site with some documents that a few user has access to.

I want that when these users are on the site, they will be able to search for the documents that is stored locally, but when they are out of the site they will not see these documents as search results. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible to minimize the search result into inbound. If u are open with a custom solution, then u can try pnp.sp.search.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Md. Tahmidul Abedin, you can use PnP search web part in these user accessible sites. These are detailed steps below:

1.[Install PnP search web part.](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/installation/)

2.Navigate to your site> Page. You can add PnP by creating a new site page or by selecting an existing site page.

3.Add PnP Search Box web part and PnP Search Results web part.

[image]

4.Configure PnP Search Results web part to only display results in your local site.

Query template: **{searchTerms} Path:{Your local Site.URL}**

[image]